# Is the system y[n] = x[n] + x[n-1] invertible?

Tags: signal-processing

Is the system `y[n] = x[n] + x[n-1]` invertible?
If **yes**, what's the value of `x[n]`?
If **no**, could you please introduce a counter example?

I couldn't find any counter example so I assumed the system is invertible and then tried to generate `x[n]` in terms of the output `y` but it always lead to a signal depending on a previous input.

`x[n] = y[n] - x[n-1]`

`x[0] = y[0] - x[-1]`   --- *1*

`x[-1] = y[-1] - x[-2]`  --- substituting into *1*:

`x[0] = y[0] - y[-1] + x[-2]`,

and so on.. the resulting signal will always depend on another input. Does this imply non-invertibility of the system? if yes, do I not need a counter example?

Note: this isn't a homework question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework with no attempt shown.

Comment: This question is not actually a homework question "the question in homework asked if the system is causal" and I did solve that.
I didn't know I should post my attempts though, will update the question.

Comment: [First try searching on the internet...](https://www.google.com/search?q=y%5Bn%5D+%3D+x%5Bn%5D+%2B+x%5Bn-1%5D+invertible) => [First hit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453938/is-yn-xn-xn-1-invertible-system)

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried searching on electronics stackexchange only. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for wanting to know more than the homework assignment asks for

Comment: As you've added your reasoning, I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjustment to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453938/is-yn-xn-xn-1-invertible-system/1700642#1700642

Take 
$$ x_1[2n] = 1 \text{ and } x_1[2n-1] = -1 $$
and
$$ x_2[2n] = 2 \text{ and } x_2[2n-1] = -2 $$ for all \$n\in \mathbb{N}\$.

Both have output \$y[n]=0 \$. The system cannot be inverted: one  output cannot distinguish at least two different inputs.